# How to make the decimals superscript, or subscript, in PHP?

Tags: php, subscript, superscript, decimal

I have this code:

```
<?php echo $price; ?>
```

which gives me this result:

```
1,500.99
```

Is there any way I can make the decimals superscript or subscript?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** This code works like a charm (thanks to David Thomas):

```
$parts = explode('.', $price); 
echo "$parts[0].<sup>$parts[1]</sup>";
```

but if I have a price like this: 1,500.99€ it superscripts the € sign as well. Can this be stoped? To not superscript it if it's not a number, or to superscript only 2 characters after the dot?

Comment: Yes, there is. Use CSS. Do some research.

Comment: Yes, but following the question suggests that the OP first needs to retrieve the numbers following the decimal point and then wrap those numbers in the relevant HTML tag. The question might be relatively simple, but I don't think it's worthy of a close-vote since there is, at least, a valid question being asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is currently untested, but I think that's as simple as:

```
$parts = explode('.', $price);
echo "$parts[0].<sup>$parts[1]</sup>";
```

References:

- [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).
- [`<sup></sup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/sup).

Comment: Just a quick one :) If I have a price like this: 1,500.99€ it superscripts the € sign as well. Can this be stoped? To not superscript it if it's not a number, or to superscript only 2 characters after the dot?

Comment: Yeah, it's possible; but in that case you'll be looking at regex solutions and while I'm okay with JavaScript regex, php still manages to confuse me, some.

Comment: So, no quick fix to your code? Ok, I'll try to search for it ;) Thanks for everything, you've been very helpful. Your code is very simple, yet effective, thanks again.

Comment: No luck. I edited my initial question, so hopefully someone will make a fix for it.

Comment: Post a different question, don't just edit to add more and more. Particularly since the question you initially asked has been answered. Also, *first* do a search on the site to see if you can find any PHP questions and answers that might be relevant.

Comment: Ok, I'll do what you've suggested, thanks a lot ;) I always search first, but sometimes I just can't find and/or figure it out how to do it :) Take care buddy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use html sub and sup tags:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_sup

An example code could be:

```
echo preg_replace('/\.([0-9]*)/', '<sup>.$1</sup>', $price);
```

Answer (score 0):

With HTML and CSS, here is an example:

```
<style type="text/css">
.superscript {
    font-size: xx-small;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.subscript {
    font-size: xx-small;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
</style>

<body>

<table>
<td class="superscript"><?php echo $price ?></td>
<td class="subscript"><?php echo $price ?></td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code:

```
<?php
$val = 10009.99;
echo set_sub_dec($val);

function set_sub_dec($val,$type="sub",$attrib=""){//use "sub" or "sup" or any other HTML tag with attributes
    if(!is_string($val)){
        $val = strval($val);
    }

    $val = split("\.",$val);

    return $val[0].".<$type $attrib>".$val[1]."</$type>";
}

?>
```